# Displaying List of Uploaded Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form where users can upload files and then view a list of their uploads. I'm running into two issues:

- List of files isn't appearing when page loads. The SQL Query is valid.
- When user uploads a file, a NullReferenceException because the file list model isn't being loaded. I'm not sure how to pass this model into view after the upload. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Controller for fetching list of datasets is below. The controller for uploading datasets is different, of course, but it accepts an HttpPostedFileBase and a datasetName. It only returns ViewBag.error/ViewBag.message.

```
public ActionResult upload(DatasetViewModel model)
        {
            List<DatasetDetail> model2 = new List<DatasetDetail>();
            var connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                try
                {
                    // Your code
                    con.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", con))
                    {

                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT datasetid, datasetname, timestamp FROM datasets WHERE userid = @userid";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters["@userid"].Value = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();


                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            var u = new DatasetDetail();
                            u.datasetid = reader["datasetid"].ToString();
                            u.dataset = reader["datasetname"].ToString();
                           /* u.timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["TIMESTAMP"]);*/
                            model2.Add(u);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Catch exception
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Close the connection
                    con.Close();
                }
            model.datasetlist = model2;
            return View(model);
        }
```

View:

```
    @model WebApplication12.Models.DatasetViewModel

    <div style="width: 320px;">
        <h2>Manage Datasets</h2>
<a href="~/Content/ExcelTemplate.xlsx">Download Excel Template</a>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("upload", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Post,
                                                  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary()

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Dataset Name:</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" id="datasetname" name="datasetname" />
            </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" id="dataFile" name="upload" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-block" />
                    </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div id="response"></div>
    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)</div>
    }
    @if (ViewBag.Error != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-error" role="alert">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Error)</div>
    }
    <div>
        @foreach (var u in Model.datasetlist)
        {
            <b>u.dataset</b>
        }
    </div>
```

Relevant Models:

```
public class DatasetViewModel
{
    public List<DatasetDetail> datasetlist { get; set; }
}

public class DatasetDetail
{
    public string datasetid { get; set; }
    public string dataset { get; set; }
   /* public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }*/
}
```

Comment: After successfully uploading, do not return the same view. Do a redirect to another GET action where it will read the data and display.

Comment: @Shyju I should note that right now the Upload action is in an iFrame. So RedirectToAction loads the entire page in that iFrame.